# Android Layout Params change ONLY width and height

Tags: android, view, parameters

I know how to set the width and the height of a view using `LayoutParams` via doing the following:

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = height/7;
params.height = height/10;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Now, as soon as I wanna apply the same height and the width to another button, I need to create another LayoutParams or overwrite the existing one like here:

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params2 = but2.getLayoutParams();
params2.width = height/7;
params2.height = height/10;
but2.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

I have about 50 buttons in my application and I doubt it is considered good code to get all the Params in order to only change the width and the height - I want to keep the remaining params (toLeftOf, [...]).

Is there a way to ONLY change the width and the height of the params but keep the rest of the parameters? So it then looks like something like:

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = height/7;
params.height = height/10;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
button2.setLayoutParams(params);
button3.setLayoutParams(params);
butt[...]
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do all the buttons have the same width and height?

Comment: width!=height, but height(button)==height(button+1) and width(button)==width(button+1)

Comment: Is that for all the buttons? Or for 2 only?

Comment: All of them. Sorry for that mathmatic depiction; Whatever button you look at, the next one has the same Params

Comment: How are you creating your buttons? Programmatically or using a layout XML file?

Comment: By XML. And it's actually a custom class of RelativeLayout but that shouldn't matter for now.

Comment: Have you tried initializing `params` with the parent view instead? Like this `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height/7, height/10);`. And then reusing `params`.

Comment: view.getLayoutParams().width = 400;
view.requestLayout();

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The whole purpose of using method `getLayoutParams()` is to take the exisiting ones from a `View` (that keep all the rules and stuff). Then you can modify specific parameters of those `LayoutParams` and keep the rest unmodified. Therefore you **need** to call `getLayoutParams()` and modify the returned object if your `Views` vary in settings in xml. In case they were using the exact same rules in xml, you could do it just like you wrote in your last example.

What I would advice you to do is just to make a method that would wrap the whole process of updating `LayoutParams`. Like so:

```
private void setDimensions(View view, int width, int height){
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

That would simplify your code significantly, because then you can just call this method for every single of your buttons, with proper values for width and height.

```
setDimensions(button, height/7, height/10);
setDimensions(button2, height/7, height/10);
setDimensions(button3, height/7, height/10);
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Kotlin** we can do it shorter and more elegant:

```
view.layoutParams = view.layoutParams.apply {
    width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
}
```

Comment: This is nice, although I prefer a extension function because it can automatically do the setLayoutParams. (I'll post another answer)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to change one parameter:

```
view.getLayoutParams().width = 400;
view.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 2):

As I cannot comment on others yet:
I created a small and elegant extension function for Kotlin.

```
fun <T: ViewGroup.LayoutParams>View.layoutParams(run: T.() -> Unit) {
    val params = layoutParams as T
    run(params)
    layoutParams = params
}
```

A use case for a view in a constraintLayout for instance would be:

```
view.layoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
    width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
}
```

If you don't need a specific implementation of LayoutParams (it is advised to do use a specific one), you can use a smaller version of the extension function:

```
fun View.layoutParams(run: ViewGroup.LayoutParams.() -> Unit) {
    val params = layoutParams
    run(params)
    layoutParams = params
}
```

..which would result in:

```
view.layoutParams {
    width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
}
```

Comment: Update: this is now a [KTX extension](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).updateLayoutParams(kotlin.Function1))

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said: you need to `getLayoutParams()`, alter the returned LayoutParams object, and `setLayoutParams()` with it (whether this is a reasonable API is up for debate).

But as **comm1x** says, Kotlin can make this really simple, and easy to read.

How about this:

```
button.alterLayoutParams { 
    it.width = height / 7
    it.height = height / 10
}
```

This requires an extension function:

```
private fun View.alterLayoutParams(callback: ((ViewGroup.LayoutParams) -> Unit)) {
    val p = this.layoutParams
    callback(p)
    this.layoutParams = p
}
```

If you wanted to apply the same layout parameters to multiple `View`s, you can do something like:

```
listOf(button, button2, button3).forEach { b ->
    b.alterLayoutParams {
        it.width = height / 7
        it.height = height / 10
    }
}
```

PS. Kotlin is nothing short of fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
view.updateLayoutParams {
    width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
}
```