# Custom WebView without layout, setLayoutParams does not work?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have а MathView([CustomWebview](https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView)), and i convert this MathView to ImageView. I make this for geting maximum perfomance in RecyclerView. But when i create Layout in view_item of RecyclerView i add only ImageView without MathView.If i set MathView(WebView) in (view_item) i get bad perfomance.

How set to created Mathview LayoutParams and then get them?

To solve this problem, I created a new project in which there is: ImageView and new MathView(), without Layout in activity_main.xml

MainActivity.java

```
MathView formula_two;
ImageView image;
String tex ="This come from string. You can insert inline formula:" +
        " \\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\) " +
        "or displayed formula: $$\\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = findViewById(R.id.image);

    //for getting attributes of layout
    XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.form);
    try {
        parser.next();
        parser.nextTag();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AttributeSet attr = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    //create MathView 
    formula_two =new MathView(this, attr);
    formula_two.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    formula_two.setText(tex);





    formula_two.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            if(progress==100)
            {

                Log.d("TAGGG", "onCreate: "+formula_two.getHeight()+"  "+formula_two.getWidth());
            //convert webview to imageview
            image.setImageBitmap(b);

            }

        }
    });




}
```

When i get height and width, i get 0;

xml/form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView android:id="@+id/formula_three"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     auto:engine="KaTeX"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
</io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
```

/layout/actiivity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are too much unclear what you want to achieve. just give id of your mathview in xml and use layout params to set width and height. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28277859/1848157   //for the reference.

Comment: If I add to layout, this will degrade performance. Because then, I want to use this in recyclerview, and as you know, if there will be a lot of webview in recyclerview, then it will not work correctly